# Debugging libcore String.java file in Android using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I am trying to resolve this issue http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24417
I want to put a break point (or logs if possible) in the **regionMatches()** method of ***java.lang.String*** package in Android ICS.
I tried multiple times using Eclipse, the code never breaks at that point. I even tried putting a break-point into a calling method and then Stepping into it, but it simply doesn't works for ***String.java*** but works fine for every other thing I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with JDK 1.5. The problem is that you class files doesn't contain some debug byte-code information. Solution, that I found was to download the source and recompile it's with debug information enabled.

See [Determine whether .class file was compiled with debug info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508235/determine-whether-class-file-was-compiled-with-debug-info) for more details.

Comment: Hey so does it mean that if I select 'debug' in **choosecombo** instead of 'release' then this libcore classes can be debugged.

Comment: I think so, but I am not sure, because I don't know what is choosecombo. What I did with JDK 1.5, I take the source, recompiled them with debug information in it and than replace old classes with new one (because there are some classes without the source, I wanted to keep them). Hope, this will help you.