# How do I step into JDK source code when debugging remotely in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I can't figure out how to step into "JDK" classes when I'm debugging remotely with Eclipse Kepler.

I have no problems stepping into "JDK" classes (like java.lang.Runtime) provided that I'm debugging a Java application launched by Eclipse (I'll call this "local"). However, when I attempt to debug the same application (launched with an InstallAnywhere LaunchAnywhere launcher) as a Remote Java Application on localhost, I can't step into JDK classes (I'll call this "remote").

In both cases (local and remote), I can step into my classes. But when I get to a method call in a JDK class while debugging remotely, Eclipse treats Step Into as Step Over. I'm using the same JDK for the local and remote debug session.

Is this an inherent limitation of remote debugging, or am I missing a configuration setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the following:

- ensure that the `Source Lookup Path` contains the `rt.jar` using [Edit Source Lookup](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-lookupsource.htm) dialog during the debug session.
- the line number attributes are included the compiled classes which you are remote debugging, check [this](http://solveme.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/unable-to-install-breakpoint-due-to-missing-line-number-attributes/) if you compiled them with eclipse.
- ensure that the remote application which you are debugging uses a JDK instead of a JRE, since JREs doesn't include debugging information

Comment: While I did try that, it didn't work, and I don't think it's necessary. In a properly configured JDK (Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Edit..), src.zip will be configured as a Source attachment for rt.jar. Regarding line numbers, that's not it because I can still step through and use breakpoints for my code.

Comment: @David the "remote" application is launched by the mentioned launcher, that might be using a JRE, which has no debug info

Comment: Katona, that was the problem -- when I modified the LAX file to tell the LaunchAnywhere launcher to use the same JRE that Eclipse was using to debug it, it worked. If you edit your answer (or add a new one), I'll upvote and accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @David I included this in my answer, and kept the other suggestions as well

Comment: Katona, did you perhaps mean to say "JRE instead of JDK" in the first clause of the third bullet point? By the way, I can't vouch for your explanation, but it did fix my problem. As an experiment, I exploded rt.jar from both the JDK's JRE and the JRE packaged with the app (and hence the JRE being used before your suggested change). Running 'javap -v' on both Runtime.class files, they seem to have roughly the same level of information. I think perhaps the real issue is that there's no src.zip for the app's JRE.

Comment: @David: I edited the third point. I still think the problem is that JRE doesn't contain the necessary information for debugging. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1508403/594406) how to check for the difference between the classes.

Comment: Katana: you're right. javap -l revealed that the LineNumberTable is missing in the JRE rt.jar .class, but not in the JDK rt.jar .class.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the src.zip inside the JDK folder please add it to the debug configuration as an external archive in the source tab

Answer (score -1):

**window->preference->java->install->click add->standard VM->next:
JRE HOWM :JDK PATH(NOT JRE PATH!)**

if no source in rt.jar
you should on rt.jar source Attachment to configure the source path.
that's all