# Log4j2 failing to output calling file and line number

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am using log4j2 to output statements for a log file in my Java application. When run it in my IDE, the output looks correct, but when I generate the desktop app (Maven), the output does not look correct.

Any ideas how to correct the file/line number?

Example output from IDE:
12-13-2023 15:20:49,443 -0500 [JavaFX Application Thread] WARN  (LineChartController.java:797) - Please verify debug log format and serial data integrity.

Example output from desktop app:
12-13-2023 15:20:49,443 -0500 [JavaFX Application Thread] WARN  (null:-1) - Please verify debug log format and serial data integrity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">c:/temp/logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Loggers>
        <AsyncLogger name="com" level="DEBUG" additivity="false" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToRollingFile"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
    </Loggers>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="LogToRollingFile" filename="${basePath}/STAG.log" filepattern="${basePath}/STAG_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz" immediateFlush="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %d{Z} [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
</configuration>
```

I have added includeLocation="true" but that did not fix the problem

I added the following to the plugin but it did not solve the problem.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>17</release>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Result of running javap -l on the class file:

```
Compiled from "LineChartController.java"
public class com.americantraction.gui.LineChartController {
  protected static int numSignals;

  protected static java.util.List<java.lang.String> columnNames;

  protected static javafx.collections.ObservableList<com.americantraction.data.serial.DebugData> filteredDebugDataList;

  protected static java.lang.String[] columnTitles;

  public java.io.File downloadedDataFile;

  static final boolean $assertionsDisabled;

  public com.americantraction.gui.LineChartController();
    LineNumberTable:
      line 49: 0
      line 120: 4
      line 215: 15
      line 230: 20
      line 247: 25
      line 254: 36
      line 261: 47
      line 268: 58
      line 275: 69
      line 282: 80
      line 289: 91
      line 296: 102
      line 303: 113
      line 310: 124
      line 317: 135
      line 324: 146
      line 329: 157
      line 334: 164
      line 341: 175
      line 353: 186
      line 361: 197
      line 369: 208
      line 378: 219
      line 386: 230
      line 401: 241
      line 406: 252
      line 411: 263
      line 416: 274
      line 421: 285
      line 426: 296
      line 431: 307
      line 436: 318
      line 441: 329
      line 446: 340
      line 451: 351
      line 456: 362
      line 461: 373
      line 466: 384
      line 471: 395
      line 476: 406
      line 481: 417
      line 486: 428
      line 491: 439
      line 496: 450
      line 501: 461
      line 506: 472
      line 511: 483
      line 516: 494
      line 521: 505
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          0     517     0  this   Lcom/americantraction/gui/LineChartController;

  public void initialize();
    LineNumberTable:
      line 530: 0
      line 531: 4
      line 532: 8
      line 533: 12
      line 534: 16
      line 535: 20
      line 536: 24
      line 539: 28
      line 543: 60
      line 546: 70
      line 547: 85
      line 548: 100
      line 549: 110
      line 550: 126
      line 552: 150
      line 553: 158
      line 554: 169
      line 558: 183
      line 564: 197
      line 572: 206
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          0     207     0  this   Lcom/americantraction/gui/LineChartController;
        158      49     1 inputDialogs   Lcom/americantraction/gui/elements/InputDialogs;

  static {};
    LineNumberTable:
      line 49: 0
      line 186: 16
      line 193: 26
      line 205: 32
}
```

Comment: is -Dlog4j.configuration= passed to VM argument ? the IDE might be using default console logger . is the pattern  also in the property file ?

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Where is log4j2.xml located so the application can find it?

Comment: @queeg I am using IntelliJ and the log4j2.xml file is located at root/src/main/resources.

Comment: @satyesht I did not pass that statement to the virtual machine. I was under the impression that it was not needed since the file is in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that Maven generates the `*.class` files without DEBUG information, so that the name of the source file and the line numbers got lost/are not part of the compiled code. This can be checked with `javap` – refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1508403/1554195) on stackoverflow.

Example output from IDE: `12-13-2023 15:20:49,443 -0500 [JavaFX Application Thread] WARN (LineChartController.java:797) - Please verify debug log format and serial data integrity.`

Example output from desktop app: `12-13-2023 15:20:49,443 -0500 [JavaFX Application Thread] WARN (null:-1) - Please verify debug log format and serial data integrity.`

The `…(LineChartController.java:797)…`/`… (null:-1)…` is the name of the source file (not provided by the Maven build) and the line number (replaced by -1 for the Maven built program) where the log message was issued. Refer to the JavaDoc for [`StackTraceElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) for additional details.

See also the [documentation for the `javac` command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/javac.html) and there look for the `-g` option.

For configuring Maven, see the [documentation for the Apache Maven Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) and there the parameters `<debug>` and `<debuglevel>`.

Comment: I added the specified parameters to the compiler plugin but it did not fix the problem. I am using jpackage to create the installer. I wonder if something with it needs modified?

Comment: Try `javap -l` to check whether the respective class has a LineNumberTable. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1508403/1554195

Comment: And if the class `LineChartController` is not part of your *source* code, Maven (or the installer) probably pulls another version of the respective library than your IDE … changing the compile switch will then make no difference.

Comment: The LineNumberTable is displayed when running javap -l on LineChartController.class so I am still very confused why the desktop applications log file is not writing the source file and line number.....

Comment: @92awdGSX – Ok … – but you have checked that class file from the desktop application, not from the IDE? Both were built from the same source, but that does not necessarily mean that both are bitwise identical. But if they are identical, I am also confused.

Comment: I did check the one from the application jar file and it contains the same information as the one created by the IDE. I am at a loss because all indicators point to the log working for the desktop app.