# Fastdebug/debug builds for JDK 7

Tags: java

I'm searching for debug (or fast debug builds as they call it I guess) of the JDK to enable printing assembly generated at runtime and other diagnostics required when hunting down performance issues. As it stands, I can't seem to find a "ready" fast debug build binary bundle which can be directly used. Can someone please help me out in giving a download link or at least providing hints as to what would be the path of least resistance to get those builds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say about "hunting down performance issues".
I can suggest you to use some profiler tool, like http://visualvm.java.net/ or tptp inside eclipse.

But, if you really want the fastdebug budle, you can download then at: http://download.java.net/jdk6/6u25/promoted/b03/index.html

Comment: +1, thanks for the reply. BTW, when I meant hunting down issues, I was more so referring to understanding how things work under the hood just out of curiosity. BTW, the link has fastdebug builds for JDK 6, is there any place I can get them for JDK 7?

Comment: Sorry, I dont know, I dont use JDK 7 yet.