# Eclipse: Can't watch local variables of static methods in a jar file class

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm trying to work with some code provided as a part of an Algorithms class.  I'd like to watch local variables in some static methods of a class contained in a jar file.  The file is algs4.jar, the class is DoublingRatio.class, and the static methods are main() and timeTrial().

Here's what the project looks like:
[image]

Here's what happens:

[image: Local variables don't show]

I can set the breakpoint and stop execution, but the variables in the static method don't show in the Variables window.  I've tried setting "Show Static Variables" by selecting it from the down-arrow in the Variables window, still no luck.  I've tried right-clicking the variable and selecting "Watch" and I get this:

[image: Expression doesn't work either]

I'm calling the DoublingRatio.main() method from my HelloWorld.java class.  Not sure if that makes a difference.  I can view local variables in the HelloWorld.main() method.  I've also tried taking HelloWorld.class out of the loop by setting DoublingRatio as the starting class in the project settings.  That configuration still doesn't work, can't see the local variables in the main() method.

**How can I watch the variables in DoublingRatio.main()?**

Comment: Hm i remember on a feature called "Debug Informations", get sure you compile using something like `javac -debug:true,vars,lines`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found the problem:

[Locally declared variables can not be inspected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271521/locally-declared-variables-can-not-be-inspected)

It would appear that this jar file was not compiled with debugging attributes.  I copied the DoublingRatio class to a class in my primary package and was able to inspect local variables in the copy.