# How to check local method variable while debugging using eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am debugging my code using Eclipse IDE. But, problem is I am not able to check values in the local method variables. When I do right click on the local variable and `inspect` that I get an error as `variable cannot be resolved`.

What do I do to see values in those variables?

Comment: For what language? If it's Java, are you debugging with source?

Comment: @NEO , Did your problem solved??

Comment: @gowtham Nopes... I am in the same scope of the method as that of local variable. and, Specifically I am debugging values under for-each loop. but, after setting Watch or Inspect, I get same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open **Variables** view in Eclipse. Click on `Window->Show View->Other` and type Variable in search box.

[image]

Note that local variables are marked as **"L"** symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Add a breakpoint to the method you want to debug. You can not check local variable unless you are in the method. As local variables have scope of the block of the method, they will be inaccessible unless method is executing and thus you are getting "variable can not be resolved" message.

You can add a `watch` by selecting variable and right click->watch to directly see variable value in `Expressions` view in debug perspective.

Comment: I am in the same scope of the method as that of local variable. and, Specifically I am debugging values under for-each loop. but, after setting Watch or Inspect, I get same error message. Sample code for inspecting value of local variable "x" :- for(int x : G.adj[V]){   if(!marked[x]){   //perform some operations  }  }

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the scope of the variable.
And it all depends on where your control is while debugging,

If your control is in the method, then when you inspect you will be able to see the value, like this

[image]

And if your control is not in that method and if you try to inspect the value, then you see `variable cannot be resolved`, as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271521/locally-declared-variables-can-not-be-inspected): you cannot watch or inspect the variables, because you didn't compile the class with debug information. You have to add the `-g` option to your javac command