# Local variables' values not showing using Eclipse remote debugging

Tags: eclipse, maven, remote-debugging, local-variables, oc4j

I have a struts project built with Maven on Eclipse, and I have oc4j server my local machine that I link to in Eclipse (in the server tab). I set my breakpoints, start the server in the debug mode, add the application to it on Eclipse, deploy the application using the enterprise manager, call the URL from my browser.

The application stops at the breakpoints as expected, but Eclipse can't evaluate the local variables' values though It can evaluate both static and instance variables.

What is causing this and how can I solve it?

Comment: this is the best I could reach but It didn't solve my issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271521/locally-declared-variables-can-not-be-inspected/940988#940988

Comment: Did you try compiling with the -g flag? `javac -g`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Locally declared variables can not be inspected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271521/locally-declared-variables-can-not-be-inspected)