# Debug Java code - cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, debugging

At the moment I try to debug the class `java.awt.Component`. If I try to `inspect` a computed local variable (by typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) I get the following message:

[image]

But the variable must be initialised at the moment!

Do you now that issue? Can you help me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The source/class files from the JDK are compiled without debug information and therefore eclipse can't inspect these vars. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271543/562363) for more information.

To do this you need to get a different rt.jar or [compile it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/940988/562363)