# is there a way I can get the value of method parameter belong import class at debug stage

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I use **eclipse** to develop java program. About the below code segment:

```
public class Boot {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr = {1,24,2,12};
        Arrays.sort(arr);////////make breakpoint!!!!!!!!!!!!
        System.out.println(arr);
    }
}
```

I make a breakpoint at `Arrays.sort(arr);` And when I debug this code segment, the thread will be suspended at this breakpoint, then I move the mouse on *(arr)* it will display {1,24,2,12} [as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuOXR.png).

Then I step into this method `Arrays.sort(arr)` and of course I come into the `sort method` of **Arrays** .

> Then my question come, I move the mouse on **int[] a** (the parameter of this method) it dont display the content of **a** which should be {1,24,2,12} this is the info it [display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBWBx.png)

---

my question is that whether there exist a way I can see the *content of a {1,24,2,12}*
or that is to say whether there exist a way by which we can see the value of variable belong to **import class**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Variables view](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fvariables%2Fref-variables_view.htm) in eclipse debugger mode.

And here's an explanation of why you're not able to see the values on mouse over: https://stackoverflow.com/a/271543/2061329